# Soundcloud track /download slug no longer working

Tags: soundcloud

Soundcloud has feature that allows any track to auto download if you add "/download" to the end of the track URL.

We have made use of that feature for many years on our soundcloud hosted podcast:

```
http://techzinglive.com
http://soundcloud.com/techzing
```

As of a few days ago the feature seems to have stopped working.

Now that we have 300 episodes it would be quite difficult to go back and retrospectively change the URLs by copy pasting the download link for each episode.

a) Is there any way Soundcloud could fix this?

b) Is there an alternative that does the same thing?

Example:

```
168: TZ Interview - Patrick Collison / Stripe
~~~
http://soundcloud.com/techzing/techzing-168 (regular link)
http://soundcloud.com/techzing/techzing-168/download (auto download link)
```

Note: I posted this here as directed by the soundcloud support page.

Comment: FYI - Here is the page where soundcloud ask for support questions via stackoverflow: https://developers.soundcloud.com/support

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer to the question is that SoundCloud no longer support the download slug option. But you can get it to work using their API.

**Backend (PHP)**

```
<?php

    $yourSoundCloudClientId = '<CLIENTID>';
    $yourSoundCloudTrackUrl = 'http://soundcloud.com/techzing/techzing-001';

    if ( ! $trackData = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url={$yourSoundCloudTrackUrl}&client_id={$yourSoundCloudClientId}")) )
    {
        die('Could not get the track because Soundcloud is down, or somethign else weird is happening.');
    }

    header("Location: {$trackData->download_url}?client_id={$yourSoundCloudClientId}");

?>
```

**Frontend (JS)**

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
var yourSoundCloudClientId = '<CLIENTID>';
var yourSoundCloudTrackUrl = 'http://soundcloud.com/techzing/techzing-001';
SC.initialize
({
    client_id: yourSoundCloudClientId
});
SC.get('/resolve?url='+yourSoundCloudTrackUrl).then
(
    function(track) 
    {
        $('#trackDiv').html('<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/'+track.id+'&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>');
    }
);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="trackDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Forgive the malformed HTML... but, you know, it works ;)